# SPSS :Loop through the values of variable

Tags: loops, spss

I have a dataset that has patient data according to the site they visited our mobile clinic. I have now written up a series of commands such as freqs and crosstabs to produce the analyses I need, however I would like this to be done for patients at each site, rather than the dataset as whole. 
If I had only one site, a mere filter command with the variable that specifies a patient's site would suffice, but alas I have 19 sites, so I would like to find a way to loop through my code to produce these outputs for each site. That is to say for i in 1 to 19:
1. Take the i th site
2. Compute a filter for this i th site
3. Run the tables using this filtered data of patients at ith site

Here is my first attempt using DO REPEA. I also tried using LOOP earler.
However it does not work I keep getting an error even though these are closed loops.
Is there a way to do this in SPSS syntax? Bear in mind I do not know Python well enough to do this using that plugin.

```
*LOOP #ind= 1 TO 19 BY 1.
DO REPEAT #ind= 1 TO 20.
****8888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888   Select the Site here.
COMPUTE filter_site=(RCDSITE=#ind).
USE ALL.
FILTER BY filter_site.
**********************Step 3: Apply the necessary code for tables

*********Participation in the wellness screening, we actually do not care about those who did FP as we are not reporting it.

COUNT BIO= CheckB (1).
 * COUNT FPS=CheckF(1).

 * COUNT BnF= CheckB CheckF(1).
  VAL LABEL BIO 
1 ' Has the Wellness screening'
0 'Does not have the wellness screening'.
*VAL LABEL FPS
1 'Has the First patient survey'.
 * VAL LABEL BnF
1 'Has either Wellness or FPS'
2 'Has both surveys done'.

FREQ BIO.

*************************Use simple math to calcuate those who only did the Wellness/First Patient survey FUB= F+B -FnB.
*******************************************************Executive Summary.


 ***********Blood Pressure.
FREQ BP.

*******************BMI.
FREQ BMI.

******************Waist Circumference.

FREQ OBESITY. 


******************Glucose.

FREQ GLUCOSE.

*******************Cholesterol.

FREQ TC.



************************ Heamoglobin.

FREQ HAEMOGLOBIN.



*********************HIV.


FREQ HIV.

******************************************************************************I Lifestyle and General Health.
MISSING VALUES Gender GroupDep B8 to B13 ('').
******************Graphs 3.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this just Frequencies you are producing? Try the SPLIT procedure by the variable RCDSITE. Should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

SPLIT FILES allows you to partition your data by up to eight variables.  Then each procedure will automatically iterate over each group.

If you need to group the results at a higher level than the procedure, that is, to run a bunch of procedures for each group before moving on to the next one so that all the output for a group will be together, you can use the SPSSINC SPLIT DATASET and SPSSINC PROCESS files extension commands to do this.

These commands require the Python Essentials.  That and the commands can be downloaded from the SPSS Community website (www.ibm.com/developerworks/spssdevcentral) if you have at least version 18.

HTH,
Jon Peck

Answer (score 0):

A simple but perhaps not very elegant way is to select from the menu: Data/Select Cases/If condition, there you enter the filter for site 1 and press Paste, not OK.

This will give the used filter as syntax code.

So with some copy/paste/replace/repeat you can get the freqs and all other results based on the different sites.